# Create different dataframe inside of a 'for' loop

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a dataset that looks something like the following. I would like to create dataframes that contains only texts for each authors, for example as you can see the df1 contains only texts from the author0, etc. Is there any way to do that for many authors?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'text' : ['text0', 'text1', 'text2'],
    'author': ['author0', 'author1', 'author1'],
    'title': ['Comunicación', 'Administración', 'Ventas']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[df["author"]=="author0"]

df2 = df[df["author"]=="author1"]
```

I have tried this, but it's not working

```
list_author = df['author'].unique().tolist()
for i in list_author: 
  dt_str(i) = dt[dt["author"]=="i"]
```

It would be helpful if the data frames have the name df_'author' (eg df_George)

Comment: You do not want to create variables on the fly.  However, you can certainly create a dictionary of dataframes, where the key is the author name.  `dt_dict[i] = dt[dt["author"] == i]`.  But why isn't it just as easy to work with the whole dataframe?

Comment: @Tim Roberts I would like to split the dataframe based on each author. I would be grateful if you could give me an example of what you mean using dictionaries.

Comment: I gave you the exact code.  Just replace your `dt_str(i)` line with mine, after you create the dictionary with `dt_dict = {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have separate dataframes per author, use a `dictionary` with the author names as the keys. See the below example:

```
data = {
    'text' : ['text0', 'text1', 'text2'],
    'author': ['author0', 'author1', 'author1'],
    'title': ['Comunicación', 'Administración', 'Ventas']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_dict = {}
for author in df['author'].unique():
    df_dict[author] = df[df['author']==author]

print(df_dict.keys())
#dict_keys(['author0', 'author1'])

print(df_dict['author0'])
#     text   author         title
# 0  text0  author0  Comunicación

print(df_dict['author1'])
#     text   author           title
# 1  text1  author1  Administración
# 2  text2  author1          Ventas
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get the difference between your code and mine. If I have 200 authors, I cannot do it manually to save each dataframe per authors, like df1 = df_dict['author1']. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: You can't create variables like this, so saving the different data frames in dictionaries it's the best approach

Comment: Each dataframe that contains only rows from 1 author is saved in the dictionary dynamically, where the key is the author's name and value is the dataframe for that author. Only the printing is hard coded, to demonstrate that all your authors have their own key in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I get your point!